# POWER BI - why is IF Statement now showing correct output?

Tags: powerbi

I Have 3 dates Enddate= '25/01/2022', MidPoint = '25/08/2021' and Startdate= '25/03/2021'
I need a measure which says if the date is greater than mid point but less than enddate then 'Last'.
If date is less than midpoint but greater than startdate then 'Prior'
I have tried the query below but its returning blank for all dates :

````
WeeklyClass = if(
                    (datevalue('GroupSalesData'[ShortDate]) >= datevalue('GroupSalesData'[midpoint])
                    && datevalue('GroupSalesData'[ShortDate]) <= datevalue('Dates'[End]))
                    , "Last"
                    , if(
                        (DATEVALUE('GroupSalesData'[ShortDate]) <= datevalue('GroupSalesData'[midpoint])
                            && DATEVALUE('GroupSalesData'[ShortDate]) >= DATEVALUE('Dates'[Start]))
                    ,"Prior")
                )```
Any idea as to why or perhaps provides a solution

Thanks
````

Comment: The expression itself seems fine (why are you storing the dates as text and using datevalue, instead of storing as dates and just comparing them directly?) but perhaps what you are missing is that expression should be used as a calculation column in the GroupSalesData table and not as a measure.

Comment: i thought as much but the date values (startdate, enddate and midpoint) are stored as measures and it returns blank because the values are not available when columns are calculated?

Comment: Can you add the expression for the date measures as well?

Answer (score 0):

If conditions return blank if the condition is false, and no value is specified for the false condition.

Can you try to change the formula like this:

```
var _date = datevalue('GroupSalesData'[ShortDate])
return if(_date>=datevalue('GroupSalesData'[midpoint]),if(_date<=datevalue('Dates'[End]),"Last"),if(_date>=DATEVALUE('Dates'[Start]),"Prior"))
```

If you still facing issues, can you please sample data of the GroupSalesData table so that it can be easier to understand your problem and help you better